# Why is my code using a different elif statement?

Tags: python

So I was making a mini talk bot, and if I ask anything but hello, it replies with "I'm OK"
I'm not the best at python so I might just be missing something.

code:

```
print("Hello, I am Squeep Bot, my current purpose is to have meaningless conversations with you, please speak to me formally, I can not understand other ways of saying things")
while True:
    userInput = input(">>> ")
    if userInput in ["hi", "HI", "Hi", "hello", "HELLO", "Hello"]:
        print("Hello")

    elif ("how", "HOW", "How" in userInput)and("are", "ARE", "Are" in userInput)and("you", "YOU", "You" in userInput):
        print ("I'm Ok")

    elif ("whats", "WHATS", "Whats", "what's", "WHAT'S", "What's" in userInput)and("favorite", "FAVORITE", "Favorite" in userInput)and("colour", "COLOUR", "Colour" in userInput):   
        print ("I like Green")

    elif ("what", "WHAT", "What" in userInput)and("is", "IS", "Is" in userInput)and("favorite", "FAVORITE", "Favorite" in userInput)and("colour", "COLOUR", "Colour" in userInput):   
        print ("I like Green")

    else:
        print("I did not understand what you said")
```

compiler:

```
Hello, I am Squeep Bot, my current purpose is to have meaningless conversations with you, please speak to me formally, I can not understand other ways of saying things
>>> hi
Hello
>>> how are you
I'm Ok
>>> whats your favorite colour
I'm Ok
>>> fafasfdf
I'm Ok
>>>
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It's significant for Python, and the version above shouldn't run at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`("how", "HOW", "How" in userInput)` isn't doing what you think it does.

I just creates a `tuple` with 3 values:

`("how", "HOW", False)` (or `True`) but the tuple is "truthy" and it always enters the first `if`.

You could unfold using `or`, but in that case, the best would be to do:

```
if "how" in userInput.lower() ...
```

so all casings are handled.

To handle your multi-match, the best way would be using `all` actually:

```
ui_lower = userInput.lower()  # only perform `lower` once
if all(x in ui_lower for x in ("how","are","you")):
```

Will return `True` if all substrings are in `userInput` (lowercase).

Since you seem to have trouble adapting this to your code, here's a simplified version without interactive input:

```
def analyse(user_input):
    ui_lower = user_input.lower()
    if ui_lower in ["hi", "hello"]:
        r = "Hello"
    elif all(x in ui_lower for x in ("how","are","you")):
        r = "I'm Ok"
    elif all(x in ui_lower for x in ("what","favorite","color")):
        r = "I like Green"
    else:
        r = "I'm unable to comply"
    return r

for s in ("what's your favorite color","show you are strong","hello","Drop dead"):
    print("Q: {}".format(s))
    print("A: {}".format(analyse(s)))
```

output:

```
Q: what's your favorite color
A: I like Green
Q: How are you today?
A: I'm Ok
Q: hello
A: Hello
Q: Drop dead
A: I'm unable to comply
```

Note that the code has its flaws: it finds substrings, so `show you are strong` matches like `How are you today` because it finds the substrings, even if `show` isn't `how` and the order is different.

For "serious" sentence analysis, I'd suggest that you look into [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/) (natural language toolkit) library which has a python interface.

Comment: after doing that to all of them, now it says hello to everything

Comment: You must have some errors on the sideI will try to provide a full working code tonight.

Comment: Thanks! Its appreciated!

Comment: consider accepting the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: It works until I add a input and change the forced input to user input, then it splits it like each letter is a phrase.

Comment: that's because you're _iterating_ on user input using `for` like in my example. Don't do that.